# Microsoft Visual Studio 2013 hangs for a second each time a control is edited or clicked on in the Designer

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, windows-forms-designer, freeze

I'm working with VS to create Windows Forms Applications with C#.
I recently installed MS VS 2013 on a new computer. Before that, I used VS 2013 on three other computers and never had a problem.

But now I have problem when working with the Designer. Everytime I click on a control / change any property of a control / drag a control somewhere (any interaction with controls in the Designer) Visual Studio hangs for approximately a second before I can continue my work. When VS hangs, my cursor rapidly flashes...

I googled for two days already but couldn't find my exact problem.
However, I tried some solutions for general performance problems:

- I turned off the hardware acceleration of VS
- I started VS as an administrator
- I reinstalled VS

But my problem still exists, so maybe someone of you can help me

System Info:

- Windows 7 Professional 64-bit
- HP ProBook 6560b
- CPU: i5 2410M
- GPU: AMD Radeon HD 6470M
- 4GB RAM

I hope I properly described my problem, if you need any further information let me know

EDIT: I have this problem with one particular project that I built with my old computer. It has three Forms with something around 100 controls in total
When I create a new project, I do NOT have this problem
But my old computer had worse hardware and did not have this problem...

Additional Info: I think it is a rendering issue. When I scroll down in the Desginer VS hangs a lot and my cursor goes crazy. When I change a property of a control and Click outside of VS on some other program, it changes the properties without any delay

Comment: Does this happen in all projects, or in one particular project?

Comment: Try using `Procmon` and see if there are any failed `WinAPI` or `Registry` calls when opening the designer.

Comment: MatthewWatson : Wow, why did I not try this yet :D It does not happen with a newly created project! I will update my problem description

Some1Pr0 : Thanks, I will try this!

Comment: @Some1Pr0 It was my first time using Procmon, but I noticed that when I click on a control there appear a lot of entries in procmon. They are all basically "NotfiyChangeDirectory" - Operations and Detail says something along these lines: "FILE_NOTFIY_CHANGE_FILE_NAME   FILE_NOTFIY_CHANGE_DIR_NAME" and so on

Comment: @Some1Pr0 : Oh yes, now I've seen some failed Registry entries! 
Operation is "RegOpenKey", Result is "NAME NOT FOUND" and Detail "Desired Access: Read"

Comment: Can you underatand if it is a massive eanough amount of reads which can make your loading slower, are those reads the same key many time, if so which key?

Comment: The Registry operations are restricted to two keys, but there are only 3 - 5 per second (if they appear at all, they are rather rare)
But the "NotfiyChangeDirectory" - Operations I mentioned before appear really often, so they might be the problem?

Comment: @Some1Pr0 Do you have any further advise for me? :/

Comment: Are they the same files all the times? are the operations failing? sorry it's a bit hard to help in this kind of things without trying things myself

Comment: @Some1Pr0 Yes, it is always the same directory (C:\User\myName). My VS projects are in this dir (but a little deeper of course C:\User\myName\Documents\VS2013\...). Operations do NOT fail. 
Nonetheless, I appreciate your help :)

Comment: Try to look for failed operations and fix them, you can make loading times for many apps shorter like that (office applications, vs, other stuff)